# Magento1 :shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

our product has both special price and shopping cart price rule I need to apply shopping cart price rule on normal price of the product, not the special price?

particular wholesale customer1. >> this is a customer group?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of setting the special price rule, you need to set bellow configuration at **"Actions tab".**

**Attribute " Special Price " is not assigned**
[image]

Comment: i follow your answer but here not apply discount our requirement wise because  if any product use base and special price  than i our customer group is wholesalers than discount apply on base price wise .here is apply on special price wise by default magento and your answer wise not apply discount in checkout page please if another solution reply me

Comment: Please reply my comment